# Fixed Navigation when Scroll down

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed, navigationbar

The script is working, when scrolling down it does place the navContainer at the top of the window but unfortunately there're a couple of small issue that are driving me bananas!

1. I want this function to get fired right after the the outerHeight of the header (page title). With the code i have it does it but a few pixels a little before than it should. Take a look at the letter "g", .navContainer should stick to the top right after it passes the last pixel of the letter(which is the height of its container) but it does it a few pixels before (i would say 10 px). **Fixed**
2. If the view port is less than `960px` the issue is that the `.f-nav` goes `100%` of the viewport but what i want it to go `100%` of its parent container .container -its parent container is inheriting this attributes from its parent container .wrapper, which has a `max-width:60em; margin: 0 auto;`and `padding:0em 0.5em`;

I'm more concern about the second issue than the first one, any idea how to solve this issue? Let me know if you want more details. The snippet below is also [on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbOMdx).

```js
function testFunction(){/*alert("test");*/
   
 $(window).scroll(function () {
         var nav = $('.navContainer');
    var headerHeight = $('.headContainer').outerHeight();
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
 //  $('.f-nav').width($('.nav').width());
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
            $('.nav-wrapper').css('background','#f7f7f7');
  } else {
   nav.removeClass("f-nav");
  }
 });
    
    };
    testFunction();
```

```css
body{margin:0;}
.wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0em 0.5em;
  max-width:60em
}
.container{
  background:gray;
}
.navContainer{
  border-top:2px black solid;
  border-bottom:2px black solid;

}
.navContainer ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
.headContainer{
  height:100%;
  color:white;
  font-family:'tahoma';
  font-size:50px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.navContainer ul{background:green;}
.navContainer li{
  display:inline;
  padding:0px 50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:red;
  margin:0px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
.wrapper img{width:100%;}
.f-nav{ z-index: 9999; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%;max-width: 60em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <div class="headContainer">Page Title</div>
  <div class="navContainer">
    <ul>
      <li> Home 1</li><li> 
      Home 2</li><li> 
      Home 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-640-1920-9.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is that the `Body` has `margin: 10px;` that's why the navigation has a fixed top earlier than you have expected it. Set the `margin` to `0`, it will make a smoother transition.
2. Are you missing some codes in your Codepen because there is no `.fixed-nav`, unless you meant `.f-nav`. But the parent of `.f-nav` is `.container`. So you need to clear this up.

Comment: 1. This solution fixes the problem. 2. i'm sorry, i meant to say f-nav. f-nav parent is indeed .container, but .container is inheriting its width from the .wrapper (which is the one that contains width 60em)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var header = document.querySelector('#mainMenu'); 

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
 this.scrollY > header.getBoundingClientRect().top ? header.classList.add('f-nav') : header.classList.remove('f-nav')
}, false);
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}
.rowWrap{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0em 0.5em;
  max-width:60em
}
.container{
  background:gray
}
menu.rowWrap{
  border-top:2px black solid;
  border-bottom:2px black solid;
  background:green
}
menu li {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;padding:0
}
header h1{
  height:100%;
  color:white;
  font-family:'tahoma';
  font-size:50px;
  padding-bottom:30px
}

menu.rowWrap li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0px 50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:red;
  margin:0px;
  margin-right:10px
}
article.rowWrap img{width:100%}

.f-nav{ 
    z-index: 9999; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0
}
```

```html
<header class=container>
    <div class=rowWrap>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>
</header>

<section id=mainMenu class=container>
    <menu class=rowWrap>
        <li> Home 1</li>
        <li> Home 2</li>
        <li> Home 3</li>
    </menu>
</section>

<section class=container>
    <article class=rowWrap>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-640-1920-9.jpg" />
    </article>
</section>
```